# Can't see the background image on Android app

Tags: android, kotlin, background-image

> After USB debugging of my Kotlin code using Jetpack-Compose, I cant see any background image on my android app.
> The source code is as follows:

```
package com.example.happybirthday

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Row
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.Surface
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.res.painterResource
import androidx.compose.ui.text.style.TextAlign
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.sp
import com.example.happybirthday.ui.theme.HappyBirthdayTheme
import androidx.compose.foundation.Image
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Box
import androidx.compose.ui.layout.ContentScale
import androidx.compose.ui.res.stringResource


class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            HappyBirthdayTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    GreetingText(message = stringResource(R.string.happy_birthday_text), from= getString(
                        R.string.signature_text
                    ))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun GreetingText(message : String , from: String, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    // Create a column so that texts don't overlap
        Column(
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
            modifier = modifier
                .padding(8.dp)
                .fillMaxSize()
        ) {
            Text(
                text = message,  //This GreetingText() function displays text in the UI. It does so by calling the Text() composable function....predefined
                fontSize = 97.sp,
                lineHeight = 116.sp,
                textAlign = TextAlign.Center
            )
            Text(
                text = from,
                fontSize = 36.sp,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(16.dp)
                    .align(alignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally)
            )
        }
}

@Composable
fun GreetingImage(message: String , from: String, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    val image = painterResource(R.drawable.androidparty)
    //create a box to overlap image and texts
    Box {
        Image(
            painter = image,
            contentDescription = null,
            contentScale = ContentScale.Crop ,
            alpha = 0.5F
        )
        GreetingText(
            message = message,
            from = from,
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .padding(8.dp)
        )
    }
}

@Preview(
    showBackground = true,
    )
@Composable
private fun BirthdayCardPreview() {
    HappyBirthdayTheme {
        GreetingImage( stringResource(R.string.happy_birthday_text),
            stringResource(R.string.signature_text))
    }
}
```

The background image is in app > res > drawable > androidparty.png(nodpi)

I USB-debugged and ran the app on android phone(installed it), but the background is not visible but the rest works fine. How do i get the background image on the app ?

Answer (score 1):

In your MainActivity class, you are calling the GreetingText composable instead of GreetingImage. i.e In your MainActivity class change:

`GreetingText(......)`

to

`GreetingImage(......)`

that should fix it